# Compare datetimes from SQL Server table with a datetime from user and get the date from table closest to the user's datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table in SQL Server 2014 with time stamps.

This is my table:

[image]

I want to compare each time stamp from my table with a time stamp that I input and get from my table the time stamp for which the `datediff(table_timeStamp, @myTimestamp)` is the smallest. Hope it is clear what I want. This is for a function and I want to know how can I do that in the easiest way possible?

Comment: Just to be clear, your time_stamp is actually a date field and not type timestamp?

Comment: In my table the type of column 'Time_Stamp' is datetime

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 * ........... order by ABS(datediff(s,table_timeStamp, @myTimestamp) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * ........... order by ABS(datediff(second,table_timeStamp, @myTimestamp) )
```

Answer (score 0):

That query works much faster if table has an index on `Time_Stamp` column. 
The `winner` query will ALWAYS do a table scan and NEWER use index at all.

```
SELECT TOP 1 Time_Stamp FROM 
    SELECT Max(Time_Stamp) as Time_Stamp FROM MyTable WHERE Time_Stamp < @myTimestamp
UNION
    SELECT MIN(Time_Stamp) as Time_Stamp FROM MyTable WHERE Time_Stamp > @myTimestamp)
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: It is simple. In case of having Index on `Time_Stamp` my code is faster.

Comment: please [edit] your answer to add that explanation.  The other answers don't address speed at all, so that's a way to differentiate yours from them.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the closest date previous to the date input:

```
;With cteTestDates As
(
Select *, DateDiff(Second,datefield1, '2016-07-01') DateDifference
    From TestDates
)
Select Top 1 *
    From cteTestDates   
    Where DateDifference >= 0
    Order By DateDifference
```

If you want the closest date regardless if it is in the past or future:

```
;With cteTestDates As
(
Select *, ABS(DateDiff(Second,datefield1, '2016-07-03')) DateDifference
    From TestDates
)
Select Top 1 *
    From cteTestDates   
    Order By DateDifference
```